# Static HTML file directory can't be found in AWS Lambda express.js server

Tags: express, webpack, aws-lambda, serverless

I am trying to serve a static HTML file using the `res.sendFile()` method from my express.js server that is hosted on AWS Lambda using the `Serverless` framework. Assuming that I am trying to serve an HTML file from the directory `src/views/users/index.html`.

In deployment, this is the file path that I have tried to serve my HTML file from `/var/task/src/views/users/vindex.html`, but I keep getting the error `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/task/src/views/users/index.html'` when viewing the AWS Cloudwatch log.

```js
    app.use(express.static(__dirname));
    path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/views/users/index.html");
```

This is the results I get when I run `tree src` locally:

[image]

Have anyone experienced this issue before, and have solved it? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Well, after many grueling hours and trying many solutions, I have found a workaround to render the html content without actually needing to render a `.html` file.

I ended up making a helper method that returns a string of the html content and send the html content string using the `res.send()` method instead.

html helper function

```js
    export const htmlHelper = () => {
      return `<html content goes here>`;
    
    }
```

route method

```js
    app.get('/html', (_, res) => {
     const htmlString = htmlHelper();
     return res.send(htmlString);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

In express:

```
app.use('/', express.static('./src/views/users/index.html'));
```

In serverless.yml

```
package:
  patterns:
    - '!node_modules/**'
    - 'src/views/**/*'
```